# not found page - next 13

Tags: javascript, next.js13

I create not-found page named not-found.tsx in app folder. Simple:

```
export default function NotFound() {
  return (
    <div>page not found</div>
  );
```

It is work on my localhost but when i create build by `next build` and export files from "out" folder to server custom page 404 not working.
My next.config file:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  output: "export",
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },
  trailingSlash: true,

  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(mp4)$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            outputPath: "static/videos/",
          },
        },
      ],
    });
    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

My custom 404 page when route is not found

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it's not working"? Any errors in the console?